# Book on diagnostic research

Tags: references, diagnostic, medicine

Other than the excellent book *Statistical Methods in Diagnostic Medicine*, are there any other reference books on the argument? If not what are the best book which could be related to diagnostic medicine?

Comment: I see nothing off topic about this question. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: Did you mean [Statistical Methods in Diagnostic *Medicine*](https://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Methods-Diagnostic-Medicine-Xiao-Hua/dp/0470183144)?

Comment: Are you asking about books aimed at clinicians or at statisticians?

Comment: Books aimed at statisticians focusing on applications and methodologies in diagnostic medicine. @gung i corrected the title thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Pepe "The Statistical Evaluation of Medical Tests for Classification and Prediction" https://www.amazon.co.uk/Statistical-Evaluation-Medical-Classification-Prediction/dp/0198565828